# How can I hook a double click event from an ExtJs RowBody?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am using an Ext.grid.plugin.RowExpander which uses Ext.grid.feature.RowBody as the base for toggling. The grid has a double click listener that opens a window. The problem is that double clicking on the RowBody does not fire the double click event on the grid and I cannot even find how to hook the event.

Comment: Are you saying the `RowExpander` plugin isn't working? Or are you trying to make double clicking do something different, unrelated to the `RowExpander`?

Comment: The RowExpander is working. The RowExpander plugin uses the RowBody feature. I want to hook the double click event on the RowBody, created by the RowExpander, so that I can open a window to view additional detail about the record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was dumb and did not read the documentation for Ext.grid.feature.RowBody. It clearly says that the feature exposes three "additional events on the gridview" including rowbodydblclick. There is still some difficulty in knowing which row in the grid or more importantly which record the RowBody that trigger the event was part of.